# How to sort Excel data by Date in VB6

Tags: excel, vb6

i wanna sort it by date which is the mid column of my worksheet.
im getting my data from a db system but i cannot sort it in that system i need to sort the data which comes to me as this:

```
| A FIELD  | B FIELD | C FIELD | DATE FIELD | E FIELD | F FIELD | 
|  Adata1  |  Bdata  |  Cdata  | 09.05.2011 |  Edata  |  Fdata  | 
|  Adata2  |  Bdata  |  Cdata  | 03.05.2011 |  Edata  |  Fdata  | 
|  Adata3  |  Bdata  |  Cdata  | 21.05.2011 |  Edata  |  Fdata  | 
|  Adata4  |  Bdata  |  Cdata  | 01.05.2011 |  Edata  |  Fdata  | 
|  Adata5  |  Bdata  |  Cdata  | 11.05.2011 |  Edata  |  Fdata  |
```

And i should find a way to make it like this than paste to excel:

```
| A FIELD  | B FIELD | C FIELD | DATE FIELD | E FIELD | F FIELD | 
|  Adata4  |  Bdata  |  Cdata  | 01.05.2011 |  Edata  |  Fdata  | 
|  Adata2  |  Bdata  |  Cdata  | 03.05.2011 |  Edata  |  Fdata  | 
|  Adata1  |  Bdata  |  Cdata  | 09.05.2011 |  Edata  |  Fdata  | 
|  Adata5  |  Bdata  |  Cdata  | 11.05.2011 |  Edata  |  Fdata  | 
|  Adata3  |  Bdata  |  Cdata  | 21.05.2011 |  Edata  |  Fdata  |
```

so how can i do this in VB6 to Excel? I can use a helper for it and read data from it order/sort than paste back to excel but which helper OLE?

```
Dim strcnn As String
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim Cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub Form_Load()
    'Create database connection
    strcnn = "MyConnectionToDb"
    cnn.Open strcnn
    Cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
End Sub


Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cek As String
    Dim tarih As String
    'Set excel
    Set kitap = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    kitap.Workbooks.Add
    'Data Query
    cek = "SELECT * FROM DATATEST.trolololollololollololoo"
    rs.Open cek, cnn
    'If result is empty
    If rs.EOF = True Then
        'Report situation
        Situation.Caption = "Situation : is under control!"
    Else
        'Start counter
        i = i + 1
        'Add headers
        kitap.Cells(i, 1).Value = "SN"
        kitap.Cells(i, 2).Value = "OP"
        kitap.Cells(i, 3).Value = "HF"
        kitap.Cells(i, 4).Value = "UC"
        kitap.Cells(i, 5).Value = "HA"
        kitap.Cells(i, 6).Value = "UA"
        kitap.Cells(i, 7).Value = "IN"
        'While not end of file
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            'Increase the Counter
            i = i + 1
            'Add the data
            kitap.Cells(i, 1).Value = rs.Fields("SN")
            kitap.Cells(i, 2).Value = rs.Fields("OP")
            kitap.Cells(i, 3).Value = rs.Fields("HF")
            kitap.Cells(i, 4).Value = rs.Fields("UC")
            kitap.Cells(i, 5).Value = rs.Fields("HA")
            kitap.Cells(i, 6).Value = dotdate(rs.Fields("UA")) 'UA is date field, this will be the key column
            kitap.Cells(i, 7).Value = rs.Fields("IN")          'to sort all data is being saved to excel.
            'Next record
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
        'Close data connection
        rs.Close
    End If
    'Save data to excel
    kitap.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(App.Path & "\troll.xls")
    kitap.Application.Quit
    'Report situation
    Situation.Caption = "Situation : Excel Formatted Troll is Ready"
Exit Sub
Error:
    'On error close connection
    rs.Close
    'Report situation
    Situation.Caption = "Critical ERROR! : Connection has been trolled! Reset ur computer."
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you reading your data from the database? And what sort of structure are you storing it in when you receive it?

Comment: i ve given additional info about my code! i use ADODB recordset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Here is a badly shaped code but solves the problem.

```
OptionExplit
Dim strcnn As String
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim Cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub Form_Load()
    'Create database connection
    strcnn = "MyConnectionToDb"
    cnn.Open strcnn
    Cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
End Sub

'Sorting function here!
Public Function OrderByDate()
    Dim i, j, k As Integer
    Dim temp(100, 50) As Variant 
    'for my work here 100 was enough.. change it if u got more items in ur excel data.
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    'Set excel
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(App.Path & "\my.xls")
    Set xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets(1)
    'Start working on worksheet
    With xlWorkSheet
        'Start counters
        i = 2
        j = 3
        k = 1
        'Report situation
        Situation.Caption = "Situation : Ordering by Date."
        'Till Excell Book finishes
        Do While Not k = .Rows.Count - 1
            'When you reach empty cells in ur sheet it means you're at the end of ur data.
            'So finish there.
            If UnDotAndTurn(Replace(Trim(.Cells(j, 6)), ".", "")) = "" Then
                'Exit
                Exit Do
            Else
                'ReOrder the data
                If UnDotAndTurn(Replace(Trim(.Cells(i, 6)), ".", "")) > UnDotAndTurn(Replace(Trim(.Cells(j, 6)), ".", "")) Then
                    'First get the values to a template
                    temp(i, 1) = .Cells(j, 1)
                    temp(i, 2) = .Cells(j, 2)
                    temp(i, 3) = .Cells(j, 3)
                    temp(i, 4) = .Cells(j, 4)
                    temp(i, 5) = .Cells(j, 5)
                    temp(i, 6) = .Cells(j, 6)
                    temp(i, 7) = .Cells(j, 7)
                    'Then get the next value into current
                    .Cells(j, 1).Value = .Cells(i, 1)
                    .Cells(j, 2).Value = .Cells(i, 2)
                    .Cells(j, 3).Value = .Cells(i, 3)
                    .Cells(j, 4).Value = .Cells(i, 4)
                    .Cells(j, 5).Value = .Cells(i, 5)
                    .Cells(j, 6).Value = .Cells(i, 6)
                    .Cells(j, 7).Value = .Cells(i, 7)
                    'At last write the values in temp to next value set
                    .Cells(i, 1).Value = temp(i, 1)
                    .Cells(i, 2).Value = temp(i, 2)
                    .Cells(i, 3).Value = temp(i, 3)
                    .Cells(i, 4).Value = temp(i, 4)
                    .Cells(i, 5).Value = temp(i, 5)
                    .Cells(i, 6).Value = temp(i, 6)
                    .Cells(i, 7).Value = temp(i, 7)
                    'return previous data to see if its still->
                    '->higher than what data comes before it.
                    If i <= 3 Then
                        i = i - 1
                    ElseIf i > 3 Then
                        i = i - 2
                        j = j - 2
                    End If
                ElseIf UnDotAndTurn(Replace(Trim(.Cells(i, 6).Value), ".", "")) = UnDotAndTurn(Replace(Trim(.Cells(j, 6).Value), ".", "")) Then
                     'do smt here if u need to do! when they are equals to each other
                ElseIf UnDotAndTurn(Replace(Trim(.Cells(i, 6).Value), ".", "")) < UnDotAndTurn(Replace(Trim(.Cells(j, 6).Value), ".", "")) Then
                     'do smt here if u need to do! when i lower than j
                End If
                '+1 to go next data
                i = i + 1
                j = j + 1
                k = k + 1
            End If
        Loop
        'Report situation
        Situation.Caption = "Situation : Order Finished! Saving."
        'Save worksheet
        .SaveAs (App.Path & "\my.xls")
    End With
    'Save workbook
    xlWorkBook.Save
    xlWorkBook.Close
    xlApp.Quit
    'Report situation
    Situation.Caption = "Situation : Changes Saved!"
End Function

'Take date data as string and clear "." and turn it to yyyymmdd together. 
Public Function UnDotAndTurn(ByRef elem) As String
    Dim Day, Month, Year As String
    'Clear dots and spaces
    elem = Trim(elem)
    elem = Replace(elem, ".", "")
    'If result is empty
    If elem = "" Then
        'Return empty
        elem = 0
        UnDotAndTurn = ""
    ElseIf elem <> "" Then
        'Get date values
        Year = Right(elem, 4)
        Month = Mid(elem, Len(elem) - 5, 2)
        Day = Mid(elem, 1, Len(elem) - 6)
        'If "Day" is 1 charachter long than add 0 to head to get this: 09 
        If Len(Day) = 1 Then
            Day = "0" & Day
        End If
        'Return result
        UnDotAndTurn = Year & Month & Day
    End If
End Function

'i use this while i read data from my db it takes date field as numeric like 9082011
'and i turn it into 09.08.2011 date format, putting dots to make it more understandable
Public Function dotdate(ByRef elem) As String
    Dim Day, Month, Year As String
    'Get date values
    Year = Right(elem, 4)
    Month = Mid(elem, Len(elem) - 5, 2)
    Day = Mid(elem, 1, Len(elem) - 6)
    'If "Day" is 1 charachter long than add 0 to head to get this: 09 
    If Len(Day) = 1 Then
        Day = "0" & Day
    End If
    'Return result
    dotdate = Day & "." & Month & "." & Year
End Function

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim cek As String
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    'Set excel
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    Set xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets(1)
    'With worksheet
    With xlWorkSheet
        'Data Query
        cek = "Select * From DATATEST.trolololollololollololoo"
        rs.Open cek, cnn
        'Start counter
        j = 1
        'If result is empty
        If rs.EOF = True Then
            'Report situation
            Situation.Caption = "Situation : End Of File! END OF LIFE! RUN AWAY!"
        Else
            'Add headers
            .Cells(j, 1).Value = "SN"
            .Cells(j, 2).Value = "OP"
            .Cells(j, 3).Value = "HF"
            .Cells(j, 4).Value = "UC"
            .Cells(j, 5).Value = "HA"
            .Cells(j, 6).Value = "UA"
            .Cells(j, 7).Value = "IN"
            'Increase the Counter
            j = j + 1
            'While not end of file
            Do While Not rs.EOF
                'Add the data
                .Cells(j, 1).Value = rs.Fields("SN")
                .Cells(j, 2).Value = rs.Fields("OP")
                .Cells(j, 3).Value = rs.Fields("HF")
                .Cells(j, 4).Value = rs.Fields("UC")
                .Cells(j, 5).Value = rs.Fields("HA")
                .Cells(j, 6).Value = dotdate(rs.Fields("UA"))
                .Cells(j, 7).Value = rs.Fields("IN")
                'Increase the Counter
                j = j + 1
                'Next record
                rs.MoveNext
            Loop
            'Close data connection
            rs.Close    
        End If
        'Save worksheet
        .SaveAs (App.Path & "\my.xls")
    End With
    'Save workbook
    xlWorkBook.Save
    xlWorkBook.Close
    xlApp.Quit
    'Order excel file
    DoEvents
    OrderByDate
    'Report situation
    Situation.Caption = "Situation : Excel Formatted Troll is Ready"
Exit Sub        
Error:
    'On error close connection
    rs.Close
    'Report situation
    Situation.Caption = "Critical ERROR! : Connection has been trolled! Reset ur computer."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do what you want would appear to be to order the data returned from your database. Instead of:

```
"Select * From DATATEST.trolololollololollololoo"
```

Try

```
"Select * From DATATEST.trolololollololollololoo ORDER BY [Date Field Name]"
```

Comment: thats imposible for me cause my db is not a sql based db its more like IBM's AS400 db, but ur logic is true ty for ur time and answer

Answer (score 1):

To be honest - I don't understand your problem. In fact I think you created the problem yourself. Why don't you just copy the data as it is, and later run something like below?

```
'set autofilter
Me.Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).AutoFilter

'sort 
Me.AutoFilter.Range.Sort Key1:=Cells(rowDateField, 1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

Sorting done.

Comment: well my problem is i cannot sort before saving my db data to excel cause my db dont allow sorting("or orderby") so thats why i needed to save it to excel than re read it and than sort and i did it already and posted my answer down there. Every cell in a row is not connected with each other and when u order by 1 column other columns still stands same. Its cause of my db's way of pasting data.
anyway ty for ur answer its a usefull sorting way.

Comment: also lastRow and Column is unknown so i need to find it after i paste whole data and for that i search for empty entry than say there is the lastRow and Column.

Comment: lastColumn is the number of columns taken from the database, lastRow is number of rows - surely you can obtain them when you take the data from the database? I am afraid I dont understand the comments of disconnected cells. If you want to sort only one column and rest should remain the same - change the range of the autofilter. HTH

Comment: ok now i'm not getting the data from my db by colums or rows its totaly different in my db. Your logic is true at sql based db but not on mine! thats why i cannot obtain their row and column numbers. for that reason i need to check for empty cells and when i reach empty cells it means im at my last row or colum. thats the only way for me to do it. cause of my unworthy db. but i can do it after i paste all data to excel sheet and than i can use ur style.